# git sometimes loses track of 2nd svn merge parent

Tags: git, svn, merge, git-svn

G'day,

I am using git, svn and git-svn.

I have been using subversion to merge topic branches.

Occasionally, I notice that when I subsequently perform a git svn fetch, the merge info for the second parent is lost to git so in the git history the merge looks like a single, large commit instead of a merge commit which preserves the reference to the second parent. This doesn't always happen, but I haven't been able to determine the precise circumstances that causes it to happen.

Can anyone explain why this happens and what steps can be done to prevent it?

Comment: More info: the problematic topic branches are forked from a merge of other SVN topic branches. It seems SVN can't represent this complexity  in the svn:mergeinfo property.  A workaround was: delete the reference to the right branch from the svn:mergeinfo of the left branch, commit, remove the svn:mergeinfo from the right branch, commit, then remerge the right branch, resolving any property merge conflicts in favour of the left branch. Upon the subsequent `git svn fetch` a merge was recorded.

Comment: make sure that svn:mergeinfo contains all revisions until merge-base for the branch you merge; if this is not true and the branch is partly merged, it is safer not to create merge commit in Git

Answer (score 0):

This [documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) explains some of the issues integrating svn and git, and may be of help. Specifically:

> When you’ve become comfortable with a Git workflow, you’ll likely create topic branches, do work on them, and then merge them in. If you’re pushing to a Subversion server via git svn, you may want to rebase your work onto a single branch each time instead of merging branches together. The reason to prefer rebasing is that Subversion has a linear history and doesn’t deal with merges like Git does, so git svn follows only the first parent when converting the snapshots into Subversion commits.

Comment: This documentation is referring to what happens if you push a git merge into SVN. My case is the reverse - pulling an SVN merge into git. I think my case does involve SVN topic branches that are based on merges of other SVN topic branches. SVN cannot properly represent the history in the svn:mergeinfo property and so gives up and treats it as a single commit.